# How to subtract 1 from numbers matched by regular expression?

Tags: bash, awk, regular-expression

I'm trying to write a script that reduces each number in line by "1", but I'm getting all "0"s instead:

```awk
awk '{a=gensub(/([0-9]+)/,"\\1","g",$0);
     if(a~/[0-9]+/) {gsub(/[0-9]+/,a-1,$0);}
     print $0}'
```

For example, the string:

```
1,2,3,4-7
```

should result in:

```
0,1,2,3-6
```

instead I'm getting:

```
0,0,0,0-0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`awk` substitution capabilities are quite limited. `gawk` has `gensub()` that can at least include parts of the matched portion in the replacement, but no operation can be done on those.

It's possible with `awk`, but you need to take a different approach:

```
awk '{
  text = $0
  $0 = ""
  while (match(text, /[0-9]+/)) {
    $0 = $0 substr(text, 1, RSTART-1) \
         (substr(text, RSTART, RLENGTH) - 1)
    text = substr(text, RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  $0 = $0 text
  print}'
```

Or with GNU `awk` as a variation on @jofel's approach:

```
gawk -v 'RS=[0-9]+' '{printf "%s", $0 (RT==""?"":RT-1)}'
```

or

```
gawk -v 'RS=[^0-9]+' '{printf "%s",($0==""?"":$0 - 1)RT}'
```

However, here it's a lot easier with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/$&-1/ge'
```

`perl` can use capture groups (as `$1`, `$2`... and `$&` for the whole matched portion) and with the `e` flag can run arbitrary `perl` expressions with those.

Answer (score 7):

Your awk solution matches only the first number and then replaces
all other number with the first number reduced by one.

Taking your program, you can use with GNU's awk (`gawk`):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="[^0-9]"; OFS=""; ORS=""; } {a=gensub(/([0-9]+)/,"\\1","g",$0);if(a~/[0-9]+/) {gsub(/[0-9]+/,(a-1),$0);} print $0,RT}'
```

But this can be simplified to

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="[^0-9]"; OFS=""; ORS=""; } {if(length($0)) {print ($0-1);}print RT}'
```

Or with comments:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { 
    RS="[^0-9]";  # set the record separator to a regexp matching all 
    OFS="";  # no output field separator
    ORS="";  # no output record separator (we use RT)
 } 
 {
     if(length($0)) { # if number found
       print ($0-1); # print it decreased by one
     }
     print RT # output current field separator (=non-digit). 
 }'
```

Each non-digit is used as record separator and re-inserted with the print statement.

Here a solution in python:

```
python -c 'import re,sys; print re.compile("\d+").sub(lambda i: str(int(i.group())-1),sys.stdin.read()),'
```

Comment: It's actually worse than that. It's the entire line, interpreted as a number, less one.

Answer (score 1):

### Using generic (non-GNU) "awk":

I would suggest a separation of the input lines into arrays of values and separators. Then, modify the values and recombine them with the separators:

```
awk '{
    split("0," $0 ",0", numbers, "[^0-9]+"); # make sure each line starts and ends with a number
    split($0, sep, "[0-9]+");
    res = ""; j = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < length(numbers); i ++) { # ignore the dummy numbers added above
        res = res sep[j++] (numbers[i] - 1);
    }
    print res;
}' file
```

Comment: Does this work if the line starts with a non-digit? It seems also sometimes to insert some wrong "-1".

Comment: @jofel You're right, this did not handle lines beginning or ending with a delimiter correctly. I've fixed my answer accordingly.